# Confusion about Stream

Tags: c#, stream

I am trying to download a file from SharePoint.
After making some research,I got this and it says that it will be better for the performance if we use buffer.

Remark - file is SPFile

```
using (System.IO.Stream strm = file.OpenBinaryStream())
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int bytesRead;
    do
    {
        bytesRead = strm.Read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
        response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        response.Flush();
    } while (bytesRead > 0);
}
```

Once we assign like `response.BinaryWrite(file.OpenBinary());`, are we getting the whole stream in strm object (start consuming RAM) ? Let's say the file is 10MB , then this strm will be 10 MB in RAM ?

Or it will start consuming memory once we start reading ? `bytesRead = strm.Read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `Stream` is a pipe, not a bucket; it doesn't (usually) "contain" the data - it just manages *access* to the data. In terms of the example, the data loaded by your app at any time is `BUFFER_SIZE` bytes (plus any other buffers used by any other layers).

You also don't really need to `Flush()` on every write (although a `Flush()` at the end might be appropriate).

What you have is fine; the only thing I'd say is that you can simplify this in recent version of .NET:

```
using (System.IO.Stream strm = file.OpenBinaryStream())
{
    strm.CopyTo(response);
    // response.Flush(); // optional: only included because it is in the question
}
```

Comment: > Thanks for your answers.
What if I do directly **response.BinaryWrite(file.OpenBinary());** instead of looping ? it will have memory issue ?